# KeyBinding - RelayCommand is in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I bind my textboxes to ViewModel class. But, button command (it's a RelayCommand, extended from ICommand) I bind to UsersView.xaml.cs. In UsersView.xaml.cs constructor I have this:

```
DataContext = UserVM;
btnAdd.DataContext = this;
```

This is how I bind button - it works.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Add}" Content="Add user" />
```

Now, I want to add KeyGesture for that button but I can't set DataContext for InputBindings and compiler can't find this Add command in UsersVM class.

```
<UsersView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F10" Command="{Binding Add}" />
</UsersView.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Have you tried `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Add}"`? It's a shot in the dark, but it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this on a Window and this is the code I used...

```
<Window
   x:Class="MVVMExample.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:myViewModels="clr-namespace:MVVMExample"
   Title="MainWindow"
   x:Name="MyMainWindow"
   Height="350"
   Width="525">
```

Notice that I set the `x.Name` of the Window.  Then in my KeyBinding, I did this...

```
<Window.InputBindings>

    <KeyBinding
        Key="F10"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=MyMainWindow, Path=DataContext.AddPersonCommand}" />

</Window.InputBindings>
```

The `AddPersonCommand` is my ICommand from my ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, it works! I set x:Name="MyUsersView" and used this binding: <KeyBinding Key="F10" Command="{Binding ElementName=MyUsersView, Path=Add}" />. This binding works for button command binding, too (removed btnDataContext from UsersView.xaml constructor). Thx.

Comment: Well if it works, and you are satisfied, mark it as the answer.